# How to use SignalR in aspnetcore 2.0, with c# and html/js for front end

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, nuget, signalr

Am trying to install SIGNALR to my asp.net project, but when adding the Nugets, it keeps pushing an error that the "Package xxx was restored using .NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1 instead of the project framework .NETCoreApp, Version=v2.0". I get this error on several Nugets. I tried to re-install all Nuget one by one but same result when I arrive at some particular one like SIGNALR.

I believe I might have something wrong in the setup, but as am new to asp.net, would love a pointer. Read the literature but could not find the answer to this issue.

It also looks like SignalR might only be available for netcore 2.1 later this year but am looking for a way to use it, in a simple app.

[image]

Comment: .NET Core different from regular .NET. The package you got is for regular .NET. SignalR for .NET Core is beta. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-getting-started-with-signalr/

Comment: Thank you @hatcyl, was just looking at the very same page actually. Does this mean I can still use the beta for my simple app, following the steps in the link you posted?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to have the latest stuff installed, after that no extra nuget package needed. (Although you will need npm)

Comment: Yes will do, but am wondering if not easier to roll back to aspnet instead of core to get all solid SignalR stuff maybe then.

Comment: You'll have a easier time with regular .NET, as it's been out longer and more established. .NET Core stuff is still beta, and there might be issues here and there + incomplete stuff, but nothing to bad.

Comment: SignalR on ASP.net Core 2.0 is not available. But with the release of ASP.net Core 2.1 it will be built into it, so no nuget package will be necessary (if you're using the meta package).
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-getting-started-with-signalr/
So if you want it for production use, you are going to have to wait out a month or 2.

Comment: For personal use, installed the Visual Studio preview and the pre-release of the core 2.1, looks good. Just have to make it work now :)

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things. 
For the latest SignalR Core bits you need to be targeting netcoreapp2.1. Preview1 and later depend on that.

If you want to just experiment with SignalR targeting netcoreapp2.0 the alpha 2 bits use netcoreapp2.0. But just to be clear the alpha bits are just a public preview and should not be used for production applications.

The main thing here though is that you are using the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` packages. Those will not work on Core.

Comment: Thx, just installed the pre-release of the new 2.1 core, no need for nugets indeed, included with it.